# Is there any alternate way to bring lambda variables outside the lambda loop

Tags: java, filter, collections, java-8

```
Result result = ParcelFromDB.getParcelcodes
.stream()
.filter( itr -> itr.getCode().equals(parcelReq.getCode())
.findAny()
.orElse(null);

if(result == null){ ... }
```

After this, I have to take the existing code which is from the DB and based on that I will proceed on the rest of the logic.

I am unable to take the "itr" value as it is a final variable. Please suggest if there is any alternate way to carry the value of "itr" outside the lambda? I have tried other ways but as per the code base, this is the only way I should do it.

Comment: can you please format your code and give little more details

Comment: If you want to use some internal variable from the inner code, you shouldn't use lambda, but instead use a classical loop. But better, rethink your logic so that this access isn't necessary.

Comment: Please be more clear, what do you mean *bring outside the lambda*? Do you want something like this `itr -> someVariableOutsideLambda = itr`?

Comment: Why don’t you use the `result` variable? If you are interested in the nonmatching elements, just reverse the filter condition.

Answer (score 1):

Lamba expression [is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) an anonymous, yet still *method*, an *Anonymous Method*.

Variables declared within the scope of method are local to that scope and there's no way to reference them outside of that scope.

Comment: lambda expression is not a method, that document says you can "think" about it like this, but no more.

Comment: @Eugene it's a value, if you'd like to be so picky, and then it's not rather a function. Want to discuss what its bytecode is representing? my aim was to make this clear to someone asking the clarification. Actually, it's invoked in the same semantics as function, only the difference is that it's not belonging to the instance of class itself. By the way, several other documentations refer to it as exactly the *Anonymous Method*.

Answer (score 1):

`itr` in the lambda expression represents an item in the stream. One of them (due to your usage of `findAny`) is returned as the `result` variable, which you can use later. Instead of just terminating the stream, you could use `forEach` and operate on all the elements:

```java
ParcelFromDB.getParcelcodes()
            .stream()
            .filter( itr -> itr.getCode().equals(parcelReq.getCode())
            .forEach(itr -> {
                // Do something interesting with the item
            });
```

Comment: I think the question asks more about whether one can refer to the variable declared inside the lambda.